# Where can I find data for multiple linear regression?

Tags: regression, dataset

I'm doing a paper about multiple linear regression where I need to have 1 dependent variable and 3 independent variables.

Anyone have some good data that I can use? I already tried Google Database, Kaggle,  and FBI data base, but can't find what I want. My professor wants me to get a correlation of 6% or greater.

Comment: What is a correlation of 6% or greater, $R^2 \ge (0.06)^2 = 0.0036$?

Answer (score 2):

**It is quite subjective to recommend a specific dataset. However, I will demonstrate a solution in R, which will provide you with a convenient and fast opportunity to browse a large number of datasets. So you can select the one that is right for you.**

```
 ### Access all available datasets

 # check available datasets in all packages
   datasets.load::datasets() 

 # check datasets within a specific package, for example:
   datasets.load::getDatasetInfo("lattice") 
   datasets.load::getDatasetInfo("dplyr")

 # Selecting a specific dataset
   lattice::singer # type package name::name of dataset
   str(lattice::singer) # check variable type
```

#### **EDIT: Reproducible example added**

#### I will use 'Boston' dataset from 'MASS' package as an example

```
MASS::Boston      # inspect dataset 
?MASS::Boston     # read full variable information (e.g. per capita crime rate)
str(MASS::Boston) # check variable types
dim(MASS::Boston) # check matrix dimensions 


# correlations
m1 <- round(cor(MASS::Boston, method = c("pearson")), digits = 2) 
m1

# beautify correlation table
m1 <- as.data.frame(m1) # convert to dataframe 

m1[lower.tri(m1, diag = TRUE)] <- NA # trim lower triange and diagonal 
m1[abs(m1) < .60] <- NA              # correlations below |.60| are removed 
                                     # note: criterion chosen was arbitrary
                                     # .60^2 represents 36% percent shared variance  

# Display correlations above |.60| 
m1              # visual inspection
sum(!is.na(m1)) # print number of correlations above |.60| 


# Examples of such correlated variables 
# Per capita crime rate is correlated with accessibility to radial highways at .63
# There are other 17 examples to explore
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, ineed at lest 30 observations units

Comment: @jarwin I just checked, there are 71 units for each variable in the MASS::Boston dataset. If you find this answer helpful, could you please upvote and accept it